# Sleuth Tracing doesn't work with Spring JMS

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have 2 services, I'm trying to add log correlation with sleuth.

**first service:**
spring-boot version:1.5.9.RELEASE

**second service:**
spring-boot version:1.5.3.RELEASE

the first service sends to the second service 2 messages, one via HTTP and one via JMS

```
public void sendHeartbeatCommand() {
    Long sendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Heartbeat newHeartbeat = new Heartbeat();
    newHeartbeat.setHostname(hostname);
    newHeartbeat.setStartedAt(serverStartup);
    newHeartbeat.setLastSeen(sendTime);
    newHeartbeat.setServerLoading(serverLoading);
    newHeartbeat.setBuildVersion(serverBuildVersion);
    newHeartbeat.setTemplateVersion(templateVersion);
    newHeartbeat.setSpVersion(serverServicePackVersion);
    newHeartbeat.setHostType(HostType.NAAS);
    serverLoading = false;
    wlmJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("heartbeat.queue", newHeartbeat);
    logger.info("Sending heartbeat command to WLM " + sendTime);
}
```

and I log this:

```
2020-09-15 14:12:03.625 [74171361b0a802ca/74171361b0a802ca/NAAS] INFO  [task-scheduler-9] communication.HeartBeatSender - Sending heartbeat command to WLM 1600168323386
```

in the second service, I read the message:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "heartbeat.queue")
public void receiveHeartbeat(TextMessage message) throws JMSException {
    receive(message);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "wlm.commands")
public void receive(TextMessage message) throws JMSException {
    logger.info("Received message: {}", message.getText());

    try {
        CommandMessage cmdMsg = buildCommandFromTextMessage(message);
        findAndInvokeCommandHandler(cmdMsg);
    } catch (UnresolvableMessageType umt) {
        logger.error("Unable to properly parse message {}. Can't resolve message class: {}", message.getText(),
                umt.getMessageType(), umt);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("Unable to properly parse message {}", message, ioe);
    }
}
```

but I don't see the logs I expect to see:

```
2020-09-15 14:12:03.512 [//WLM] INFO  [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] events.CommandListener - Received message: {"hostname":"israelb-lap","startedAt":1600151393441,"lastSeen":1600168323386,"serverLoading":false,"buildVersion":"$NAAS_BUILD$","templateVersion":null,"spVersion":null,"hostType":"NAAS"}
```

my log4j files are:

first service:

```
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X{X-B3-TraceId}/%X{X-B3-SpanId}/${appName}] %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
```

second service:

```
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X{X-B3-TraceId}/%X{X-B3-SpanId}/${appName}] %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
```

properties:

first service:

```
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
spring.sleuth.messaging.enabled = true
spring.sleuth.messaging.jms.enabled=true
```

second service:

```
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
spring.sleuth.messaging.enabled = true
spring.sleuth.messaging.jms.enabled=true
```

Poms:
first service:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Edgware.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

second service:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Edgware.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

How do I correlate the log messages through Spring JMS?
What am I missing?

**Update:**

I tried it we a third service - version:2.0.1.RELEASE

the service writes and reads from the queue.
can't upgrade the version.

writing:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getWorkOrdersTest() {
    logger.info("getWorkOrdersTest ");
    wlmJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("israel.queue", "Sent from PGW");

    return  ResponseEntity.ok("PGW Test");
}
```

reading:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "israel.queue")
public void receiveT(TextMessage message) throws JMSException {
    logger.info("Received message: {}", message.getText());
}
```

configuration:

```
@Bean(name ="wlmJmsTemplate")
public JmsTemplate wlmJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    template.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
    template.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
    template.setDefaultDestinationName("israel.queue");
    return template;
}
```

properties:

```
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
spring.sleuth.messaging.enabled = true
spring.sleuth.messaging.jms.enabled=true
```

logs:

```
2020-09-16 15:04:31.312 [9ab59563855a15d9/9ab59563855a15d9/PGW] INFO  [http-nio-9093-exec-7] api.WorkOrdersApiController - getWorkOrdersTest 
2020-09-16 15:04:31.404 [//PGW] INFO  [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] events.ProvisionEventsListener - Received message: "Sent from PGW"
```

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest version of boot and sleuth cause you're using extremely old versions.

Comment: I know but upgrading is not an option in my company right now